# innerHTML won't change element

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

I have an div element ("`main`") on my page who's contents changes back and forth between two different screens (their id's are "`readout`" and "`num`"), the contents of which are stored as hidden div elements (using `display:none`). Each screen has a button which sets `main`to the other hidden div.

Since I struggled to get javascript to put `num.innerHTML` into `main` on load, I've ended up putting virtually identical content to `num` (with a different form name) into main:

```
<p>Number of Passengers per Carriage:</p>
<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" name="applesForm" onSubmit="setPassengers();">

<input type="text" name="numApples" id="numPassengers" />

<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="OK!"/>
</form>
```

`setPassengers()` successfully sets `main`'s contents to `readout`. `readout` successfully sets `main`'s contents to `num` (virtually identical to the original content of `main`). But then it won't go back to readout.

Here are `setPassengers()` and `setPassengersAgain()`, which is the same but for a different form name:

```
function setPassengers()
    {
            passengers=document.applesForm.numPassengers.value;

            document.getElementById('main').innerHTML=readout.innerHTML;
        }

        function setPassengersAgain()
        {
            passengers=document.applesFormAgain.numPassengers.value;

            document.getElementById('main').innerHTML=readout.innerHTML;
        }
```

So my question is:
1)Why isn't `num` changing to `readout`?
2)Is there a way to load `num` straight away on page load so as to simplify the code?

EDIT: I can use onload, which means that `num` is the only bit that's broken...

EDIT 2: Here are the hidden div's:

```
<div id="readout" style="display:none">
<p>Throughput per hour:</p>
<p id="output">--</p>

<p>Average Dispatch Time:</p>
<p id="avDisTime">--</p>

<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" name="dispatchForm" onSubmit="dispatch();i++;">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Press on Dispatch!"/>
</form>
<br/>

<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" name="resetTimesForm" onSubmit="resetTimes();">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Reset Times"/>
</form>

<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" name="resetAllForm" onSubmit="resetAll();">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Reset All"/>
</form>
</div>

<!--back to default page-->
<div id="num" style="display:none">

<p>Number of Passengers per Carriage:</p>

<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" name="applesFormAgain" onSubmit="setPassengersAgain();">

<input type="text" name="numApples" id="numPassengers" />

<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="OK!"/>
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: Lack of details, in particular the markup where `main` is defined.  You need to show enough code to have a working example.  Posting code works, jsfiddle is nicer.

Comment: Edited to include the two hidden div's

Comment: There is still no element with the ID of `main` in the HTML you are giving us.

Comment: At no point are you filling a variable `readout` as in `readout.innerHTML`. You are missing a `var readout = document.getElementById('readout');` somewhere.

Comment: The whole lot is there: http://pastebin.com/WnGMWx4x I've commented out the original contents of `main` and put `num` into it with onload.

Comment: @Michael I replaced the `readout.innerHTML` with `document.getElementById('num').innerHTML` but that doesn't seem to be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post your HTML code, so I don't know how it looks like, but you could use somethin like:

HTML:

```
<button id="changeMain">Change #main</button>
<div id="main">
    <div id="readout" class="screen show">
        Readout
    </div>
    <div id="num" class="screen">
        Num
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main>.screen{display:none;}
#main>.screen.show{display:block;}
```

JavaScript:

```
var els=[document.getElementById('readout'),document.getElementById('num')],current;
function addClass(el,c){
    var arr=el.className.split(' ');
    if(arr.indexOf(c)>-1){return;}
    arr.push(c);
    el.className=arr.join(' ');
}
function delClass(el,c){
    var arr=el.className.split(' ');
    var i=arr.indexOf(c);
    if(i===-1){return;}
    arr.splice(i,1);
    el.className=arr.join(' ');
}
document.getElementById('changeMain').onclick=function(){
    if(!current){
        for(var i=0,l=els.length;i<l;i++){
            if(els[i].className.indexOf('show')>-1){
                current=i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    delClass(els[current],'show');
    current=(current+1)%els.length;
    addClass(els[current],'show');
}
```

[**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/CUgqh/](http://jsfiddle.net/CUgqh/)

**Explanation**:

If you want some content insode `#main`, you should place inside it (hidden or shown). Then, we hide all `.screen` with `#main>.screen{display:none;}` except `.screen.show`: `#main>.screen.show{display:block;}`.

Then, JavaScript code:

First we create an array with the elements:

```
var els=[document.getElementById('readout'),document.getElementById('num')],current;
```

And a function which adds/removes a class `c` to the element `el`:

```
function addClass(el,c){
    var arr=el.className.split(' ');
    if(arr.indexOf(c)>-1){return;}
    arr.push(c);
    el.className=arr.join(' ');
}
function delClass(el,c){
    var arr=el.className.split(' ');
    var i=arr.indexOf(c);
    if(i===-1){return;}
    arr.splice(i,1);
    el.className=arr.join(' ');
}
```

And we create an event to the button:

```
document.getElementById('changeMain').onclick=function(){
    if(!current){
        for(var i=0,l=els.length;i<l;i++){
            if(els[i].className.indexOf('show')>-1){
                current=i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    delClass(els[current],'show');
    current=(current+1)%els.length;
    addClass(els[current],'show');
}
```

The code above does:

- If it's the first time the current `els`' index (`current`) is undefined, we search which element has the class `show` by default.
- It removes the class `show` to the current shown element, so it disappears.
- It adds 1 to `current` (or it becomes 0 if it was the last `els`' element
- It add class `show` to the current element, so it appears.

Comment: Thanks although a lot of that went over my beginner's head! It does indeed work but I feel I'll have to sit down and understand it before I can justify using it ;)